# Use grep to match lines which contain a particular character and are x characters long

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to learn regex and how to use it. I have been trying to write a regex for `grep` to show me words which contain the letter e and are 8 characters long.

So far I came up with `\w+.i\X{8]`, but I know it's dead wrong and I should also account for any spaces in the data I work with and exclude them.

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: I was trying to use grep with this, but I figure I should be using sed.

Comment: You have two requirements and need to use a *positive lookahead* for one. For example, `^(?=.{8}$)[a-z]*e[a-z]*$`, with the *case indifferent* flag set. The beginning-of-line anchor and positive lookahead, `^(?=.{8}$)`, asserts that the line or string contains exactly 8 characters (any characters). The remainder matches `"e"` preceded and followed by zero or more letters (which might include other `"e"`'s). If you want to the string to contain  exactly one `"e"`, write `^(?=[a-z]{8}$)[^e]*e[^e]*$`.

Comment: Or in case of only word characters `\b(?=\w{8}\b)[^\We]*e\w+\b` https://regex101.com/r/xcORzb/1

Comment: Suggestion: You say that you are trying to learn regex. Although lookarounds are very useful and powerful, I would not suggest that their are a good starting point for regex.

Comment: Do it in 2 steps: grep for 8 chars then pipe to grep for e

Comment: Feyd, it is instructive to compare the first regex I gave in my comment above with the one offered by @Thefourthbird. Firstly, 4th's shows that mine could be simplified to `^(?=[a-z]8$).*e`. Beyond that, 4th's will match every word in a string having the desired properties, whereas mine is intended to test individual words.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `grep`, you may use

1. To match *lines* that are 8 characters long and contain `e` letter: `grep -P '^(?=.{8}$).*e' file`
2. To extract *words* that are 8 characters long and contain `e` letter: `grep -oP '\b(?=\w{8}\b)\w*e\w*' file`

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/wx4VbK/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/wx4VbK/2).

Please note the different options: `-P` enables PCRE regex syntax, and `-o` forces `grep` to output substrings matched, not whole lines (that is why the first regex only has `.*` before `e`, `.*` after `e` would be redundant).

**Regex details**

- `^(?=.{8}$).*e`

  - `^` - start of a string
  - `(?=.{8}$)`  - a positive lookahead that requires the string to be 8 chars long
  - `.*`- any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
  - `e` - `e` char.
- `\b(?=\w{8}\b)\w*e\w*`

  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `(?=\w{8}\b)` - 8 word chars followed by a word boundary must be present immediately to the right of the current location
  - `\w*` - 0+ word chars
  - `e` - a `e` letter
  - `\w*` - 0+ word chars

Replace `\w` with `[[:alpha:]]` (or `\p{L}`) if you need to match  letters only.

Answer (score 0):

You could assert 8 word characters, match word characters until the first occurrence of `e` followed by optional word characters.

```
\b(?=\w{8}\b)[^\We]*e\w*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xcORzb/1) | [Bash demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BqSS1uEQBRGTmpSskojOSlBRqFNKLUgsUdAPyFdRjkjTsbWPKqy1qY5I0o@NiwlNjtVJjyrXU//8HAA)

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?=\w{8}\b)` Positive lookahead, assert on the right 8 word chars followed by a word boundary
- `[^\We]*` [Negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), match 0+ occurrences of a word char except e
- `e` Match `e`
- `\w*` Match 0+ occurrences of a word char

For example

```
echo "test testing atesting atestingb" | grep -Po '\b(?=\w{8}\b)[^\We]*e\w*'
```

- To make use of the lookahead, use `-P` or `--perl-regexp`
- To print only the matched parts, use `-o` or `--only-matching`

Output

```
atesting
```